# The right use of the Context

Tags: android, memory-leaks, reference, android-context

I use `Context` pretty often in my applications and I have heard that it often causes memory leaks and other problems so I have a couple of related questions.

What `Context` is best to use: should I always use `getApplicationContext()` or, if possible, `Activity` like with `getActivity()` in a `Fragment` or `this` in an `Activity` or the `Context` object that usually comes as a parameter from constructors or methods like `onReceive()` if I am inside a `Broadcast Receiver`?

How to release the `Context` related objects? Simply assign `null` to variables that hold a reference to `Context` object when I don't need it anymore?

What if I had used some `Context` to instantiate a `Toast`, `ProgressDialog`, `TextView` or another object? Should I release references to these objects too to avoid memory leaks?

Is it a good practice to keep `Context` object in a global variable? Because I often need it in inner classes or methods.

I hope to get some clear clarifications, explanations, links to related topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the `Context` reference for the component, and by that I mean, use `this` for `Activity` and `Service`; use the `{@param context}` for `BroadcastReceiver`.

Only use `getApplicationContext()` for **Singleton** that have to be init in `Application#onCreate()`

Comment: What to use inside a `Fragment`?

Comment: use `Fragment#getActivity()`

Comment: How about storing `Context` in a global variable if later I need it for example in an inner class `OnClickListener`?

Comment: why not use `MyActivity.this`, `MyService.this`, `getActivity()` (for fragments)? Also avoid globals variables, it kills **OOP** concept :)

Comment: Thank you very much for making things clear. But I still wait for others advices :]

Comment: `context.getApplicationContext()` should be also used in threaded processes when on risk of the original context is destroyed before finishing current thread

Answer (score 3):

Different context have different capabilities (for example, only Activity context can start another Activity).

Check great article about how to use context: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

One of the common pitfalls is for example, to use Activity context on AsyncTask. The major problem here is that the activity could be finished (and the context destroyed) while the AsyncTask is still working. If it tries to use the context for any operation, it will fail. In this case, is much better to use the context received in the constructor (or any other method) to retrieve the Application context.

Comment: Nice example of `Activity` and `AsyncTask`. Thank you.

Comment: Check also this article on AsyncTask pitfalls: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/06/21/the-hidden-pitfalls-of-asynctask/

Comment: How about starting an `Activity` by pressing a notification that is created and started from a `Service`? There is no `Activity` `Context` there, so how to describe the `Intent` which starts the `Activity` inside a `Service` because as you said only `Activity` `Context` can start another `Activity`.

Comment: That's why you should provide a PendingIntent to the notification manager in order to know what activity should it wake up later. Check http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#action